# How can I configure Wordpress Media Cloud plugin using Oracle Cloud Bucket system

Tags: wordpress, bucket, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Altough i'm a frontend developer with experience, i'm barely a noob in what devops and cloud infrastructure means.

**tldr;**

I'm not sure how to fill the neccesary values to integrate a **Media Cloud Wordpress Plugin** with an **Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Bucket** so I can transfer media files there when I upload anything to wordpress.

**Full Story**

I'm in a situation where I need to plug an existing friend wordpress site into an Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) bucket because the current hosting system (godaddy) storage capacity is full and he wants to move his media files from the hosting server into a dedicated bucket that can escalate accordingly.

In order to do this, I've created an Oracle Cloud Infrastructure account, created a dedicated bucket named **example-bucket** and installed the wordpress [Media Cloud Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ilab-media-tools/) with hopes of using this plugin to ease the connection between Wordpress media file and OCI storage systems

[image]

Above screenshot represents the Media Cloud Plugin setup wizard screen with the neccesary values to configure the connection:

- **Access key**: ➡️ I don't know how to get it at the oracle cloud console
- **Secret**: ➡️ I don't know how to get it at the oracle cloud console
- **Bucket**: ✅ I got it
- **Region**: I'll trust the "Automatic" option because I don't see my oracle region (sa-santiago-1) on the list
- **Custom endpoint**: ➡️ I don't know how to get it at the oracle cloud console

Comment: You could get more feedbak asking here: [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> Access Key & Secret Key: These are part of the credentials used by OCI
> to allow access to your services. You can create a new user or use an
> existing one in OCI's Identity and Access Management (IAM). Once you
> have a user, you'll need to create an API signing key, which will
> provide you with the access key ID and the secret key. Here are the
> general steps:
>
> Go to the OCI Console. Open the navigation menu and click "Identity &
> Security". Select "Users" under "Identity". Choose the user you want
> to create the keys for. Scroll down to "API Keys" and click "Add API
> Key". Choose to create a new key pair. Download the private key, which
> is your secret key. The Access Key is provided as part of the key
> creation process.
>
> Custom Endpoint: This is the URL that the plugin will use to send
> requests to your bucket. For Oracle, the endpoint URL is usually in
> the format of
> https://.compat.objectstorage..oraclecloud.com. You
> can find your namespace in the OCI console under "Object Storage"
> settings.
>
> For your sa-santiago-1 region, the endpoint might look something like
> this:

```
https://<namespace>.compat.objectstorage.sa-santiago-1.oraclecloud.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. After following your steps and Added an API key I came up with a few variables auto generated named: user, fingerprint, tenancy, region & key_file and I don't know which one of those is my "Access Key"

Comment: private key file that you downloaded when you created the API key pair. This file contains the Secret Key that you will use to authenticate.